# Sql not null on many columns

Tags: mysql

I have many tables with LEFT JOIN but at the end I would like to output only these which are not null
I can make it like

```
WHERE Country IS NOT NULL AND City IS NOT NULL AND Address IS NOT NULL
```

etc.
But is it the fastest way to get all of my SELECTED tables?
Country, City, Address is not null doesn't work.

Comment: Yes; that's how it's done

Comment: It's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

Check if column value is null then give it a integer value then add it up; if addition result is not "0" (assuming that all of the columns contain mainly alphabets with numbers etc.). Something like:

```
SELECT country, city, address, 
       IFNULL(country,1)+IFNULL(city,1)+IFNULL(address,1) AS checking
FROM test;

returns:
+---------+------+---------+----------+
| country | city | address | checking |
+---------+------+---------+----------+
|    A    |  A   |    A    |    0     |
|    B    |  B   |    B    |    0     |
|  NULL   | NULL |   NULL  |    3     |
|    C    |  C   |    C    |    0     |
+---------+------+---------+----------+
```

Then with that you can add `HAVING` like:

```
SELECT country, city, address, 
       IFNULL(country,1)+IFNULL(city,1)+IFNULL(address,1) AS checking
FROM test
HAVING checking=0;
```

This might work just well if all the columns that you're comparing doesn't have just numbers.

Another idea is using `SUM(col+col+col...)` like:

```
SELECT country, city, address, SUM(country + city + address) AS checking 
FROM test
GROUP BY country, city, address;

returns:
+---------+------+---------+----------+
| country | city | address | checking |
+---------+------+---------+----------+
|    A    |  A   |    A    |    0     |
|    B    |  B   |    B    |    0     |
|  NULL   | NULL |   NULL  |   NULL   |
|    C    |  C   |    C    |    0     |
|    D    |  D   |    1    |    1     |
|    E    |  E   |   NULL  |   NULL   |
+---------+------+---------+----------+
```

As you can see, the `SUM()` result will become `NULL` if one of the column in the operation has `NULL` values even if the other columns are all numbers. This you can also filter using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT country, city, address, SUM(country + city + address) AS checking 
FROM test
GROUP BY country, city, address
HAVING checking IS NOT NULL;
```

This will at least cover if one of the columns have numbers however will require you to list all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` due to `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` so it might not be shorter than what you already have.

[Here is a db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b8293dfd5f39f29c1f3d56e5221d852).